# Replacing standard PVC wires with silicone wires

Tags: wire, electricity

So I got my hands on a piece of silicone wire and I love that it's so flexible and puffy. And seems lighter too. Would it be a good idea to replace standard PVC cables from various small devices that I frequently use with silicone wire? Is there any downside to this?
For example I have a small car compressor with a power cord that gets tangled all the time.

Comment: There's an old motto - "If it ain't broke, don't fix it".

Comment: There's no downside with silicone insulation, but I concur with Tom. If you get the current rating wrong or do a crappy job, there will be a downside.

Comment: Electrical wires are not made from PVC or silicone.  It makes no sense to make wires from insulators.

Comment: Wire with silicone insulation tends to go where it wants to instead of where you put it.

Comment: The small car compressor working with 12 V will need a lot of current. Replacement cable should have the same cross section area at least.

Comment: Silicone has superior temperature resistance to most other insulations, however it may be more prone to splitting. Other factors can come into play depending on the application- outgassing, chemical resistance, abrasion resistance etc. There are many insulation systems on the market (eg. TKT = PTFE-Polyimide-PTFE) because needs vary.

Answer (score 1):

I bought a small lot of this type wire. It's UL listed made by a Chinese manufacturer Dongguan Sheng Pai. AWG22.

Comments.. very flexible, not just the insulation but a high strand count. Rated for 200°C. Other types of silicone may be different flexibility, so this is just one data point.

Disadvantages.. the silicone is not very robust at all, I can **easily** strip it with my fingernails. As I said in the comment above, it would be much more easily split than other typical insulation systems.